# how to configure AOLServer to use a different port than Apache2's 80

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, apache-2.2

I am using a Ubuntu virtual machine.Where I installed OpenACS which depends upon AOLServer.To do so I had first shutdown Apache on this machine and then as per instructions given here

http://openacs.org/xowiki/ubuntu

Step 1) 
 aptitude install postgresql

Step 2) 
 aptitude install openacs

I had to shutdown Apache to do above installation.
Now the installation finishes.So I can access http://localhost:8000

but when ever I try to start Apache on this machine which was shutdown during installation I see the error

```
 service apache2 start
  * Starting web server apache2 (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80  no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
```

So I thought may be OpenACS installs AOLServer so Aolserver might be listening on port 80 I check

```
 /etc/aolserver4/conf.d/openacs.sh
```

and here

```
AOL_USER=www-data
AOL_GROUP=www-data
AOL_ADDRESS=192.168.1.15
AOL_PORT=8000
RUN_DAEMON=yes
```

So AOLServer is not listening on port 80 upto here it is confirmed.

```
  netstat -tualp  | grep 80
tcp  0      0 somemachine.somedimain.:8000 *:*   LISTEN   21321/aolserver4-ns
```

so netstat shows only 8000 in  use.
Then why am I unable to start Apache in this case?

**Edit** 
as ooshro below pointed out
to check 
`netstat -tualp | grep \:www` the output
I got was
`tcp        0      0 localhost:www           *:*                     LISTEN      2883/aolserver4-nsd`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check:

```
netstat -tualpn | grep 80
```

or

```
netstat -tualp  | grep \:www
```

without 'n' options, 80 resolve to www.

Edit "/etc/aolserver4/aolserver4.tcl":

```
array set debian_config {
HOSTNAME localhost
ADDRESS 127.0.0.1
HTTP_PORT 8080
HTTPS_PORT 443
}
```

Then restart aolserver4 and apache2

```
/etc/init.d/aolserver4 restart
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: you are right the second netstat showed me aolserver-nsd listening on www service.

Comment: @Registered User I update answer

Comment: I will bookmark your answer currently for me thing has worked.

Answer (score 1):

Ok Finally I resoved this problem.The default openacs install listens on port 8000, to avoid conflict with the default aolserver listening on port 80.

I had  to  put RUN_DAEMON=no in /etc/default/aolserver4 file although all the lines of this file were commented out but I still needed to add

```
RUN_DAEMON=no
```

That is what worked for me.